# printing content of string array java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I would like to say that I have an 1 day experience with java,therefore if its a bit easy question, sorry about that.

Now, I want to show my piece of code .

I have a string array like :

```
String [] attributeNames[4];
```

I've read 4 name each of which are 64 bytes from binary file and store them into this array. (attribute name contain null-ended string max 64 byte) And then I want to print my attributeNames array and their length however, If I write :

```
for(int i=0;i<attributeNames2.length;i++){
    System.out.println(
        attributeNames2[i] +
        " length: "+attributeNames2[i].length()
    );
}
```

I got only

```
pathway             
shortest_path
path_length
avg_neighbour_number
```

as a result . Length are not printed but If I write

```
for(int i=0;i<attributeNames2.length;i++){
    System.out.println(
        "length:"+attributeNames2[i].length() + 
        "names:"+ attributeNames2[i]
    );
}
```

I got

```
length: 64 pathway
length: 64 shortest_path
length: 64 path_length
length: 64 avg_neighbour_number
```

I wonder why ? Is there anyone to help me ?

Comment: In your first attempt you are creating a 2-Dimensional array..

Comment: The output does not correspond to the code (which does not compile) - show you real code.

Comment: @TheLostMind does "string[] identifier[x];" compile to "string[][x] identifier"? (Genuine question as I've never written Java)

Comment: @TheLostMind creating 2-dim array ? ?

Comment: @TheGost Yes, It's just a hint to correct the line. :) As I wont take a step to correct it, because it may be your actual code.

Comment: @JamieTaylor - Yes... String [] attributeNames[] is same as String[][] attributeNames..

Comment: @TheLostMind I see. Thanks. That's probably the issue with OPs code, then.

Comment: @TheGost - How are u initializing String [] attributeNames[4] ?? .. Show us the code...   System.out.println(length: "+attributeNames2[i].length()+ "names:"+ attributeNames2[i] ); will not work..

Answer (score 1):

Your loop seems ok, problem probably lies in a way you are creating the array. The right way is

```
String[] attributeNames2 = new String[4];
attributeNames2[0] = "pathway";
//and so on
```

Or you can create static array which seems to me sufficient in your case

```
String[] array = {"pathway", "shortest_path", "and so on"};
```

Comment: attributeNames[0] will not be just  "pathway", instead,since I read 64 bytes. from pathway to 64 bytes there will be whitespaces. I need to remove them I think